# Invalid application of incomplete type 'Test::Impl'

Tags: c++, design-patterns, cmake, c++14

Please have a look at directory structure first [ attached at the bottom of the question end].

Following are my Cmake files :

1. Main cmake

   ```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)  
    set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

    add_executable (test main.cc)  

    target_include_directories(test PUBLIC test_include_interface)

    target_link_libraries(test PUBLIC test_test)
   ```
2. Test cmake :

   ```
    add_library(test_include_interface INTERFACE)

    target_include_directories(test_include_interface INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

    add_library(test_test STATIC test_interface.h
                                        test.h
                                        test.cc)

    target_include_directories(test_test INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
   ```

**test.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "test_interface.h"

#include <memory>

class Test : public ITest {
public:
    Test();

private:
    class Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> impl_;

};
```

**test.cc**

```
#include "test.h"


class Test::Impl {
public:
    Impl() {}
    ~Impl() {}
};

Test::Test() : impl_{std::make_unique<Impl>()} {}
```

Error :

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/memory:80,
                 from /home/vkd0726/test/test/test.h:9,
                 from /home/vkd0726/test/main.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::default_delete<_Tp>::operator()(_Tp*) const [with _Tp = Test::Impl]’:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/unique_ptr.h:292:17:   required from ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::~unique_ptr() [with _Tp = Test::Impl; _Dp = std::default_delete<Test::Impl>]’
test/test/test.h:11:7:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/unique_ptr.h:79:16: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘Test::Impl’
   79 |  static_assert(sizeof(_Tp)>0,
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Please help me understand this error and how to resolve it ? Is it a problem with the Cmake or code itself. I have seen such "Impl" design pattern use at many places but unable to write a test snippet. What is wrong here ?

**Directory structure**

[image: Directory structure]

Comment: Replace make_unique with keyword new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Test` does not contain a user defined destructor, so the compiler generates a inlined version of this destructor. Since this destructor involves logic to delete the `Test::Impl` object when the destructor of `std::unique_ptr<Test::Impl>` is invoked, you get the error your compiler complains about.

You can fix this by defining the destructor in `test.cc`:

**test.h**

```
#include <memory>

class Test : public ITest {
public:
    Test();
    ~Test(); // new
private:
    class Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> impl_;

};
```

**test.cc**

```
class Test::Impl {
...
};

...

Test::~Test() = default;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem faced with `std::unique_ptr` for **pimpl**. The primary approach would be - as @fabian mentioned - to provide a declaration fir the nesting class's destructor and define it in the same translation unit as the *pimpl* implementation (most probably as a defaulted function). But this approach might disable some corner case optimizations, due to compiler not being able to deduce the triviality of the destructor of nesting class(`Test` according to OP). Another approach would be to provide a *deleter* class for the `std::unique_ptr` and leave the nesting class`s destructor intact:

```
class test{
public:
    test();
private:
    class impl;
    struct deleter{
        void operator(impl *)const;
    };
    std::unique_ptr<impl, deleter> up_impl;
};
```

Now define the deleter's function call operator in the same translation unit as impl to:

```
void test::deleter::operator(test::impl * ptr) const
    { delete ptr; };
```

This looks a little more work. But it pays off with an implicitly defined destructor. It also better suits the rule of 0/3/5.